# facebook comment system using smarty and prestashop

Tags: api, smarty, prestashop, facebook-comments

I'm trying to add some comments box to a specific page of my website

but I met some trouble

using smarty I've seen in the documentation that in order to get the current url we should use that synthax  `{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}`

that's actualy what I did putting that code in my tpl.

```
{literal}
<div id="fcbcfooter"><div data-href="http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}

{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}" class="fb-

comments" data-width="500px;" data-num-posts="10"  data-

colorscheme="light"></div>
 {/literal}
```

The trouble I have is that it return to me that message

```
href URL is not properly formatted
```

The code for getting url does not seems to be interpreted in the source code.

anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a closing `</div>` at the end of your code block.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing `</div>` at the end of your code block  right before the `{/literal}` tag.

```
 {literal}
    <div id="fcbcfooter">
       <div data-href="http://{/literal}{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}
       {$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}{literal}" class="fb-comments" data-width="500px;" data-num-posts="10"  data-colorscheme="light"></div>
    </div>
    {/literal}
```